# Apache Flask Permission denied

Tags: python, apache, flask, файловая-система

у меня такая проблема, при попытке перезаписи файла

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'servs.json'
```

Сайт работает на Flask на Apache. Вот Conf файл

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/FlaskApp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                    Options ExecCGI
                    AllowOverride all
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

servs.json находится в /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Владельца файла и права на него можно посмотреть в терминале `ls -la /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/`.

`-rw-r--r--`, например, значит, что писать файл (write) может только владелец.

Потом записать из самого питоновского процесса (в лог, в хттп-ответ или еще куда)  имя и uid пользователя, под которым он выполняется. Возможно как-то так:
`getpass.getuser()` или `os.getuid()` или `os.geteuid()`.

Возможно посмотреть соответствие имен uid-ам `cat /etc/passwd`.

Думать дальше.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо большое